# Pulling out SVG path/group by id using PHP

Tags: php, xml, parsing, svg, path

So I'm having bit of a complex problem with trying to manipulate SVGs using PHP. I want to use PHP instead of Javascript as it's not an interactive thing I'm working on. Basically what I have is a map with various elements in it that have been assigned IDs for each of the countries. Some are groups and some are paths, something like this:

```
<svg>
    <path ... id="NO" ... />
    <path ... id="CA" ... />
    ...
    <g ... id="RU" ...>
        <path .../>
        <path .../>
        <path .../>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Essentially what I want to do is give PHP the ID of one of these objects, and it strips away everything else. So for those that are paths, it would just return (if it were given 'CA'):

```
    <path ... id="CA" ... />
```

Or if it were given 'RU':

```
    <g ... id="RU">
        <path .../>
        <path .../>
        <path .../>
    </g>
```

The reason for this is so that I can use parts of the image separately without needing to create hundreds of extra .svg files (which is a lot of work, especially when they all need updating).

Any advice would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

As svg is a XML file, you should use `DOMDocument` class. Documentation is here:

http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXml($svgFileContent);
$child = $dom->getElementById('id-of-group'); //here you have an corresponding object
$xml = $dom->saveXML($child); //xml will contain xml string
```

Comment: I wonder whether `getElementById` will work, as in XML you would need to have a DTD that defines the attributes of type `ID` (http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementbyid.php). It might be easier to use XPath with e.g. `//*[@id = 'RU']`.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give this a go soon and get back to you :)

Comment: Hmmm I've tried the solution in the original answer, and I get an error "Fatal error: Call to a member function saveXML() on a non-object". Removing the 'ownerDocument' part works, but it returns the full SVG document.

Don't seem to be able to find a method using XPath that works either (I'm probably using it wrong) as the script just stops executing haha. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry for mistake in answer. Check out the updated answer.